# can ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate be used for super column family as well?

Tags: cassandra

I am currently using the template for standard column family and it's quite convenient to me. Now I have a model that's super column family, I wonder if I can use ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate for processing super column family record/data as well. Any samples available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use SuperCFTemplate

The following is a sample of SuperCFTemplateTest in Hector test suite.

public class SuperCfTemplateTest extends BaseColumnFamilyTemplateTest {

@Test
  public void testSuperCfInsertReadTemplate() {
    SuperCfTemplate sTemplate = 
      new ThriftSuperCfTemplate(keyspace, "Super1", se, se, se);
    SuperCfUpdater sUpdater = sTemplate.createUpdater("skey1","super1");
    sUpdater.setString("sub_col_1", "sub_val_1");
    sTemplate.update(sUpdater);

```
SuperCfResult<String,String,String> result = sTemplate.querySuperColumn("skey1", "super1");

assertEquals("sub_val_1",result.getString("super1","sub_col_1"));

sUpdater.deleteSuperColumn();
sTemplate.update(sUpdater);
assertEquals("super1",sUpdater.getCurrentSuperColumn());
result = sTemplate.querySuperColumn("skey1", "super1");
assertFalse(result.hasResults());
```

}